# How to change side dynamically from Ion Menu depending of screen size?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am working with Ionic 4 and I want to change side property from ion-menu dinamically, I noticed that when you work on a big screen ion-menu is always visible or static but on small screen is hidden until you click on the ion-menu-button, so I want to place ion-menu on the left side on big screens and the right side on small screens.

app.component.html

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-split-pane contentId="main-content">
    <ion-menu contentId="main-content" type="overlay" side="{{side}}">
      <ion-content>
        <ion-list id="inbox-list">
          <ion-list-header>Menu</ion-list-header>
          <ion-note *ngIf="tokenData">
            {{ tokenData.email}} 
          </ion-note>

          <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false" *ngFor="let p of menuPages; let i = index">
            <ion-item *ngIf="menuService.showPage(tokenData, p) && p.url" (click)="selectedIndex = i; menuService.clickPage(p.code)" routerDirection="root" [routerLink]="[p.url]" lines="none" detail="false" [class.selected]="selectedIndex == i">
              <fa-icon slot="start" [icon]="p.icon"></fa-icon>

              <ion-label>{{ p.title }}</ion-label>
            </ion-item>

            <ion-item *ngIf="menuService.showPage(tokenData, p) && !p.url" (click)="selectedIndex = i; menuService.clickPage(p.code)" lines="none" detail="false" [class.selected]="selectedIndex == i">
              <fa-icon slot="start" [icon]="p.icon"></fa-icon>

              <ion-label>{{ p.title }}</ion-label>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-menu-toggle>

        </ion-list>

      </ion-content>
    </ion-menu>
    <ion-router-outlet id="main-content"></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-split-pane>
</ion-app>
```

app.component.ts (I have this function sideMenu() but is executing just one time)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Platform,MenuController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';


import { AuthService } from './auth/services/auth.service';
import { MenuService } from './shared/services/menu.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public selectedIndex = 0;
  tokenData = null;
  menuPages = [];
  side = 'end';
  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private menuService: MenuService,
    private menu: MenuController,
  ) {
    this.initializeApp();
    // Initialize BackButton Event.
    this.menuService.backButtonEvent();
    this.menuPages = this.menuService.menuPages;
  }



  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#D4AF37');
      /*
      status bar is not working with the deault styleDefault();
       this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      */
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }

  sideMenu(){
    this.menu.isOpen().then(open => { 
      if(open){
        this.side = 'end';
      }
      this.side = 'start';
     });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sideMenu();

    this.authService.getTokenData().subscribe(
      tokenData => { 
        this.tokenData = tokenData;
      }
    );
    const path = window.location.pathname.split('home/')[1];
    if (path !== undefined) {
      this.selectedIndex = this.menuPages.findIndex(page => page.title.toLowerCase() === path.toLowerCase());
    }

  }

}
```

On big screens is working correctly on the left side, see the picture
[correct side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQ0nE.png)

On small screens is showing menu on the left side but I want this on the right side
[incorrect side, it should be the right side with the ion-menu-button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ylSt.png)

Answer (score 1):

Use the "when" parameter

```
<ion-split-pane contentId = "main-content" when="lg">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check  for the screen width by

```
public devWidth = this.platform.width();
```

and on change your `sideMenu` method like this

```
sideMenu() {
   this.devWidth > 576 ?( this.side = 'end'):( this.side = 'start')
  }
```